# Powershell - how do I remove lines exceeding X characters?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have text files that Powershell works fast on, but only when the lines are reasonably short (under 4,000 characters).

If I have text files that have more than 8,000 characters on one line anywhere in the file, what would usually take 20 seconds can take 6 hours!

Is there a simple Powershell command to take out any lines that are over 4,000 characters long?

EDIT: Running in a batch file this looks like it should work but doesn't (adapted for use in a batch file, based on the Keith Miller answer below)

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object { $skipped = 0 $file = $_.FullName $result = switch -File $file { { $_.Length -le 4000 } { $_ } default { $skipped++ } } if ($skipped) $result | Set-Content -Path $file -Force} }"
```

Comment: How are you reading the files? If you're using `Get-COntent`, You're working with a collection of lines (file content split on newline), so you would test the `Length` property of the string.

Comment: I'm replacing text but it's getting stuck for hours on these long lines. `powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"`

Comment: Try this for the command: `"Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ | ForEach-Object { If ( $_.Length -lt 4000 ) { $_ -replace 'foo', 'bar' } } | Set-Content $_.FullName}"`

Comment: Cheers Keith Miller but I'm not replacing foo with bar, I just want to remove any line (regardless of what text is on the line) if it's over 4,000 characters long. That replace line I posted is just an example of the commands I am running - when running a bunch of replace commands like that, it's getting held up by lines in the text files that are enormous, so I want a separate command to remove them all before using any replace commands.

Comment: But this code simply skips those long lines, so they don't get processed & saved with the output. You can chain your replace operations and/or have multiple statements within the inner ForEach. That would accomplish both tasks in one pass, which would probably be more efficient, but you should test with `Measure-Command`. But if you want to do it seperately, the essential change would be `"Get-ChildItem '*.txt' -pv pvFileInfo | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ | Where-Object { $_.Length -lt 4000 } | Set-Content $pvFileInfo.FullName }"`

Comment: If all you’re doing is replacing text, why even bother going line by line? I think this is more of a X/Y problem: The code you have has accidental algorithmic complexity for something that could be linear speed. You should provide the exact code you use and then we can offer better help.

Comment: @Daniel B I have no exact code for removing all lines over 4000 characters, I just have replace commands that make powershell hang for hours not able to process files with lines that are so long. @Keith Miller I tried the command you posted but it left the text file I tested it on how it was. I am just tying to remove all lines over 4000 characters long at first, before running any other commands, like `-replace` etc.

Comment: is it faster, if you use the `-Raw` Parameter of `Get-Content` like this? It's all one big object instead of multiple small objects then and I'd say it should be pretty fast then: `Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace 'foo','bar' | Set-Content $_.FullName }`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with this (in a batch file)

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) | Where-Object {$_.Length -lt 4000} | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

Keith Miller answered it first but the answer is in a posted comment so I can't tick it as solved. Thanks also to Theo.

Comment: Without specifying the `-Path` on Get-ChildItem, this could easily bite you because the current working directory for PowerShell (`$pwd`) may be different to that of the cmd (`%cd%`)..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that fastest using `switch -File` to loop over the content of the files line-by-line and when it finds lines longer that 4000 characters, simply skip them:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\The\Files' -Filter '*.txt' -File) | ForEach-Object {
    $skipped = 0
    $file = $_.FullName
    $result = switch -File $file {
        { $_.Length -le 4000 } { $_ }  # only output lines that are less or equal to 4000 characters
        default { $skipped++ }         # count the lines that were longer than 4000 characters
    }
    if ($skipped) {
        # rewrite the file only if there were lines removed
        Write-Host "Replacing file '$file'"
        $result | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
    }
}
```

<sup>The brackets around the `Get-ChildItem` are there to force the enumeration of the files to finish before processing them. Otherwise, it might happen that Get-ChildItem picks up files that were already rewritten</sup>

Comment: Thanks but I have about 80 commands to run and adding commands to each is going to be far more time consuming than just having one command at the start that removes all lines with 4,000+ characters. I tried the above but I am running it in a .bat file (putting `start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command  ` before the command) and can't work out where to put the double quotes.

Comment: @bat_cmd WHY would you want to run this insde a .bat and not straight away from PowerShell? You asked for PowerShell, nothing about a .bat file which only complicates things and is totally superfluous.

Comment: @bat_cmd If you really must run it from a .bat, why not save the code as .ps1 script file and in your bat use `-File "Path\To\The\Script.ps1"` instead of `-Command`

Comment: Theo, because that means creating a .ps1 script, when I already have 80 commands all working in one batch file, it just needs a command adding at the start to remove lines over 4,000 characters long. Also, those 80 powershell commands (in a bat file) all have their special characters escaped so it works in a batch file. All of it does work, I just don't know what the command would be to remove the enormous lines that are slowing powershell down. Cheers.

Comment: @bat_cmd why wasn't all this in the question? Why can't you just run the script an then not having to worry about the performance of your batch script? Why are you adding 80 powershell commands in a batch file instead of creating one PowerShell script you run from  powershell?

Comment: Force of habit I guess, I just want one batch file to do everything. I did think about redoing the commands to run in a ps1 script but I had to escape thousands of special characters in the 80 commands and I just can't go through it all changing the escape character to a back tick for powershell, it took about 2.5 days doing the batch file and even then, that was while using another batch file that automatically escapes the characters.

Comment: @bat_cmd Also, if you want to cram a multi line script into a single line, you need to replace the newlines with a semi-colon `;`. What you did to my answer now is wrong and won't work. And I still don't understand why anyone would like to keep adding powershell commands in a batch file and not write the whole thing in PS where it could become a proper script.. You're creating al **lot** of overhead this way